# SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

hi guys i took a database snapshot .Then if i make a changes then that changes will reflect the base database or snapshot database?

When i take a database snapshot does it create a another database?

Comment: This question shout be at ServerFault.

Comment: @venkat: I recommend you go through your questions and select a "correct answer" for each one.  You haven't done this for any of your questions.  I'd be lying if I weren't doing this for selfish reasons (wanting rep) but I'm sure that the other users that you have benefited from would appreciate being marked correct as well.

Answer (score 5):

I think you may be misunderstanding what's happening here.  The point of taking a snapshot is that you can roll back all your changes to that snapshot.

This is similar to if you took a snapshot of your wife while she's young.  As she gets older, she'll get wrinkles, grey hair etc. but the snapshot won't change.  The major exception here is that you can't roll your wife back to how she looked in the snapshot.  Well not without a lot of money anyway.  It'll always represent her as she was at the very moment you took the snapshot.

So you can change the database all you want and it's not going to affect that snapshot

It does not create another database, but rather a representation of the state of that database at the exact moment you took the snapshot.

Comment: The confusion of creating a seperate database may arise from the fact that in order to create a Snapshot, the CREATE DATABASE statement is used.

Answer (score 1):

When you make changes after taking snapshot, those changes are reflected in the base database but not in the snapshot database.

When you take a database snapshot, it does not create a new database. It only creates a sparce file which stores only those pages which you update after taking the snapshot. More information on how database snapshots work could be gained from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187054.aspx)